# Data in loop is repeated

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to work something out.  I have the following

```
$fileString = "";
if (Input::hasFile('filePath')) {
    $files = Input::file('filePath');
    dd($files);
    foreach($files as $file) {
        $file->move(public_path('uploads'), $file->getClientOriginalName());

        $fileString .= public_path('uploads') . '/' . $file->getClientOriginalName();

        $uploadDoc = new ReportingDocUpload();
        $uploadDoc->filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $uploadDoc->mime = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $uploadDoc->filepath = $fileString;
        $uploadDoc->documentId = $dsReportingDoc->id;

        $uploadDoc->save();
    }
}
```

For each uploaded file, it should create a new row in the database.  The dd I have displays something like the following if I upload 3 documents

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => UploadedFile {#29 ▶}
  1 => UploadedFile {#30 ▶}
  2 => UploadedFile {#31 ▶}
]
```

So this all looks good.  So, I have a loop which should loop each UploadedFile and save it to the database.

At the moment, this kind of works.  A new row is added for each uploaded document, and everything besides one thing looks correct.

The thing that is wrong is the filePath.  For the first row, this is fine.  The second row in the database contains the filePath for both the first file and the second file.  And the third row shows the filePath for all three rows.  This should only contain the filePath for the current file.

I have looked over it, and not sure what I am missing, but for some reason this is occuring.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are setting the `$fileString=""` outside the loop, every time it goes in the loop, it concatenates to the exists.
Example

```
$fileString = ""
```

Loop 1:

```
$fileString .= a
```

Loop 2:

```
$fileString .= b
$fileString = ab
```

If you clear the the value in each loop, the result is what you need,

Example:

Loop 1:

```
$fileString = ""
$fileString = a
```

Loop 2:

```
$fileString = ""
$fileString = b
```

If you use the `=` instead of the `.=`, you might not need to assign it to an empty string inside the loop

Comment: Definately been a long day, dont believe I missed that.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Move `$fileString = "";` inside the foreach loop or change `$fileString .= public_path('uploads') . '/' . $file->getClientOriginalName();` to `$fileString = public_path('uploads') . '/' . $file->getClientOriginalName();`